# Python panda read_csv converting data during import problem with "-" value in data

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling for a while with this issue. I finally found the reason why it happens but can't find a solution yet.

I'm importing data.csv that is scraped from different resources on the web. MOst of them are strings and need to be stripped eg "%". This works like a charm using a custom converter.

But as soon as a column contains a row with "-" (no value) it gives the error *"File "D:test.py", line 14, in convert_percentage
    return float(new_val) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'"*

I'm using the following lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert_percentage(val):
    new_val = val.replace(',','').replace('%', '')
    return float(new_val)


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', na_values=['-'],   
            converters={
                'Perf Month': convert_percentage, 
                'Perf Week': convert_percentage,
                'Perf Quarter': convert_percentage,
                'Perf Half Y': convert_percentage,
                'Payout': convert_percentage,

                })
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do :

```
def convert_percentage(val):
    new_val = val.replace(',','').replace('%', '')
    try:
        return float(new_val)
    except ValueError:
        return new_val
```

You can obviously add more return depending on what you want to return. If you think the if should be checked everytime, do a conditional return. But if the error is exceptional (statistically speaking), a `try/except` block is the best choice`